# Kafka Server issue in Docker

Tags: docker, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am using docker for my sample Spark + Kafka project in windows machine.
I am facing

```
WARN ClientUtils: Couldn't resolve server kafka:9092 from bootstrap.servers as DNS resolution failed for kafka
[error] (run-main-0) org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
[error] org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
------
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers
```

Below is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
    test1:
        build: test1service/.
        depends_on:
            - kafka
    test2:
        build: test2/.
        depends_on:
            - kafka
            - test1
    zookeeper:
        image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.1.0
        ports:
         - 2181:2181
        environment:
          ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
          ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
        extra_hosts:
          - "localhost: 127.0.0.1"
    kafka:
        image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.1.0
        ports:
         - 9092:9092
        depends_on:
          - zookeeper
        environment:
          KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
          KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
          #KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL://kafka:9092
          KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "true"
          KAFKA_DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE: "true"
          KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
        extra_hosts:
          - "localhost: 127.0.0.1"
```

Below is my sample code in test2 service

```
val inputStreamDF = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "kafka:9092")
                           .option("subscribe", "test1")
                           .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
                           .load()
```

docker ps command output is

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                             COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS          PORTS                                        NAMES
4c8feb49e12b   test1                             "/usr/bin/start.sh"      About an hour ago   Up 50 minutes                                                test1
4535ce246541   test2                             "/usr/bin/myservice-…"   About an hour ago   Up 50 minutes                                                test2
733766f72adb   confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.1.0       "/etc/confluent/dock…"   About an hour ago   Up 51 minutes   0.0.0.0:9092->9092/tcp       kafka_1
d915e25cb226   confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.1.0   "/etc/confluent/dock…"   About an hour ago   Up 51 minutes   2888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp, 3888/tcp   zookeeper_1
```

Has anyone faced similar issue, how did you resolve?

Comment: Where is the Spark code running? Is it in one of the Docker containers?

Comment: yes robin, spark is running in docker container

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You try to reach kafka:9092, but docker compose has generated the container kafka_1, which is why there is no name resolution.

Docker gives internal ip to your containers, and use their container name to create an internal DNS on this network (with the embbed dns server)

Your environment variables are not changed by Docker Compose to fit the name it gives to your container.

You should use "container_name: kafka" in your container description to get a static container name.

Comment: Faeeria, added "container_name:kafka" in the docker-compose.yml but still facing same issue

Comment: Did you check the name of the produced container ?  It could also be a problem of initialization (Kafka taking too much time to initialize, and the app building anyway because the container is up)

Comment: So test1 is working and connecting to kafka fine, but test2 is not ?

Comment: As mentioned in my docker-compose.yml, test1 is kafka publisher service which publishes random numbers to kafka topic. I can see in the logs the records published,  val props = new Properties()
  props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "kafka:9092")
But in test2 (which is a receiver service), I was getting the above mentioned errors. Also yes the kafka and zookeeper names of the container are changed to kafka and zookeeper from kafka_1 and zookeeper_1 (verified with docker ps command)

Comment: Thank you Faeeria, you saved my day. Now both the services are running fine. I restarted the docker As you mentioned main error is with container_name:kafka,

Comment: Also, I am running the docker (4 services) in windows 10 pro 8GB RAM machine. While working on code, suddenly whole system hangs with 98% memory consumption. I had to restart machine again. Except docker and Intellij I am not using any application. Any help on that, I shall create new question for it if wanted.

Comment: IntelliJ loves to eat your RAM during indexing, and launching a few containers (especially databases) can also eat up your RAM.  You can use cgroups to put quotas on your containers RAM consumption, but between windows 10 pro (2GB RAM min), IntelliJ (2-4GB RAM if indexing) and the containers, 98% doesn't shock me that much

Comment: Thank you Faeeria, for now  for all services I added mem_limit: 512m mem_reservation: 128M in docker-compose.yml etc., I will use cgroups later. Now the laptop is running without hanging. Thank you very much.

Comment: Those options actually use cgroups, they are the way to manage them with Docker, so you are good to go !

Comment: Could you please mark this issue as solved ?

Answer (score 6):

Only thing you need is network. After that all services will be connected and you can use kafka:9092.

```
version: '2'
services:
    test1:
        build: test1service/.
        depends_on:
            - kafka
        networks:
          - app-network
    test2:
        build: test2/.
        depends_on:
            - kafka
            - test1
        networks:
          - app-network
    zookeeper:
        image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.1.0
        ports:
         - 2181:2181
        environment:
          ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
          ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
        extra_hosts:
          - "localhost: 127.0.0.1"
        networks:
          - app-network
    kafka:
        image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.1.0
        ports:
         - 9092:9092
        depends_on:
          - zookeeper
        environment:
          KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
          KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
          #KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL://kafka:9092
          KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "true"
          KAFKA_DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE: "true"
          KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
        extra_hosts:
          - "localhost: 127.0.0.1"
        networks:
          - app-network
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: Sure Mustafa, let me also check your updated script. Faeeria response helped me in resolving the error. I am stuck with system hanging because of docker. Any help on it would be highly useful for me.

Comment: Docker-compose has a default bridge network for all services. You also don't need `extra_hosts` for localhost

Answer (score 2):

Try with localhost and then the container port:

```
localhost:9092
```

Here is an example command for creating a topic named "orders"

```
docker exec kafka kafka-topics --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --create --topic orders --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1
```

Comment: Within the kafka container or compose network, `kafka:9092` would work too